# Blank page with webkit browser

Tags: c#, webkit

I use [webkit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet/) with the latest version
Shows an empty page to go to some websites with ssl.

```
 Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("WEBKIT_IGNORE_SSL_ERRORS", "1");
```

I used it but my problem was not resolved.